# Before assertion is not running

Tags: cypress, flakyness

I'm encountering an unusual issue. The first time I execute the code in the browser, it progresses halfway but encounters an error during the `afterEach` assertion.

Interestingly, when I rerun the same code, an error emerges during the `before` assertion. Regrettably, I'm struggling to pinpoint the root cause of this problem and comprehend the underlying reasons for its occurrence.

```js
/// <reference types="cypress"/>

describe("Validate login functionality", () => {
  //before
  before(function () {
    cy.visit("https://www.saucedemo.com/");
  });
  //beforeEach
  beforeEach(function () {
    cy.get("#user-name").type("standard_user");
    cy.get("#password").type("secret_sauce");
    cy.get("#login-button").click();
  });

  //Test1
  it("Validate link", () => {
    cy.get(
      "a[id='item_4_title_link'] div[class='inventory_item_name']"
    ).click();
  });

  //Test2
  it("Validate Add to cart", () => {
    cy.get("#add-to-cart-sauce-labs-backpack").click();
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    cy.get("#react-burger-menu-btn").click();
    cy.get("#logout_sidebar_link").click();
  });
});
```

I've made several attempts to execute the identical code on various browsers, and every time the issue persists. Despite thoroughly reviewing the code multiple times, I find myself unable to identify the source of the problem.

Kindly pinpoint the issue in code. I am using latest version of Cypress 13.0

Comment: Have you disabled Test Isolation -> https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing the saucedemo.com site has come up previously, and there is some unknown factor that makes it difficult for Cypress to handle.

A couple of modifications make the test stable

- add `chromeWebSecurity: false` to `cypress.config.js` (test with chrome browser)
- move the visit into the `beforeEach()` (don't sacrifice test isolation)

To ensure the test isn't flaky I added `@cypress/grep` to enable burn-testing.

```js
import registerCypressGrep from '@cypress/grep/src/support'
Cypress.env('burn', 10)
registerCypressGrep()

describe("Validate login functionality", () => {
  beforeEach(function () {
    cy.visit("https://www.saucedemo.com/")
    cy.get("#user-name").type("standard_user");
    cy.get("#password").type("secret_sauce");
    cy.get("#login-button").click();
  });

  it("Validate link", () => {
    cy.get(
      "a[id='item_4_title_link'] div[class='inventory_item_name']"
    ).click();
  });

  it("Validate Add to cart", () => {
    cy.get("#add-to-cart-sauce-labs-backpack").click();
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    cy.get("#react-burger-menu-btn").click();
    cy.get("#logout_sidebar_link").click();
  });
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Aladin. Your suggestion worked if I exclude "before and registerCypressGrep" from the code. I wanted to understand why the before assertion is not working. Also, when I try to implement the other suggestion related to importing "registerCypressGrep" code doesn't work and I am getting an error at run time "Webpack Compilation Error"

Comment: For question 1 - `before()` is no good in this situation, there is test isolation active - read more about it [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation).

Comment: For question 2 - I am guessing you  can fix by following the installation instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/grep).